# Default value of a integer or character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was working with C++ when this question came to my mind :-

```
int arr[10];
cout<<arr[1];
```

Gives some weird output;
but,

```
int arr[10];
arr[1]++;
cout<<arr[1];
```

This gives :-

```
Output:- 1
```

What causes this?Also what is the default character and integer array value in C++?.

Comment: You should assume the default value is "garbage" and write code accordingly.

Comment: `arr[10];` is not valid C++ syntax. Did you mean `char arr[10];`?

Comment: @scohe001 yes!.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: Unless you provide an initializer, pretend that the object has no real value and you must assign one to it before using.

Comment: Both have undefined behaviour if `arr` has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay , but what's causing it to give 1 as output?

Comment: The highly technical explanation for the behavior you're seeing is called "[demons flying of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)". You're going to have to find those demons, only they can explain how they fly out of your nose, producing these results.

Comment: @SaraswatMajumder Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SaraswatMajumder It's undefined behavior.  You just happened to get a zero in `arr[1]`, although there is no requirement that there be one.